# arduino SD card saving to file

Tags: sd-card

Can anyone assist me with read/write to a SD shield. I am using a arduino along with a SD shield (POD  uSD) I am using a ultrasonic sensor to measure a distance, it has a safety factor in it. It also measures the time a measurement was taken, I now need to save the data from the serial monitor to a file and send that file to a SD card. I cannot seem to solve the saving a file part along with the SD shield

I have wrote my code but can seem to implement the shield along with my code, I want to store my data onto a file on the SD card. I've reviewed the example provided in the library's but it won't work for me

My code is;

```c
#define redled 10
#define greenled 11
#define echoPin 12
#define trigPin 13

unsigned long interval=60000; //interval = 60 seconds
unsigned long previoustime=0;
int minutes = 0; //global variables

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600); //Set Baud rate to 9600 to match serial monitor
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(greenled, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redled, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() { 
 //----------------------------------------------------------- 
  unsigned long currenttime = millis(); //counts time in milliseconds and puts it into current time
  if ((currenttime-previoustime) >= interval) { //When time is greater 60 seconds
    previoustime = currenttime; //Make the previous time equalled to the minute to take away in the next if statement        **Time since start section**
    minutes = minutes + 1; //Add 1 minute
  }
  unsigned long time = (currenttime-previoustime) / 1000; //converts the milliseconds to seconds
  //-----------------------------------------------------------
  long distance = ultra_sensor(); //call function that now returns the distance
  //-----------------------------------------------------------
  if (distance < 4) {            // If distance is less than 4cm
    digitalWrite(redled,HIGH);   // Turn on Red LED
    digitalWrite(greenled,LOW);  // Turn off Green LED
  }
  else {                          //If distance is greater than 4cm
    digitalWrite(redled,LOW);     // Turn off Red LED
    digitalWrite(greenled,HIGH);  // Turn on Green LED
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------- 
  if (distance >= 200 || distance <= 0){
    Serial.println("Out of range");
  }
  else {
    Serial.print(distance);
    Serial.print("cm");
    Serial.print(" after ");
    Serial.print(minutes);              //Printing distance and time to serial monitor
    Serial.print(" minutes ");
    Serial.print("and ");  
    Serial.print(time);
    Serial.println(" seconds");
  }
  //-----------------------------------------------------------
  delay(2000); //Get reading every 2 seconds
}



long ultra_sensor() { //Ultrasonic sensor reading is now a function. More efficient
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);  //Set Trigger to idle
  delayMicroseconds(2); //Wait 2 microseconds
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH); //Set Trigger to high which sends out a wave
  delayMicroseconds(10); //Send the wave for 10 microseconds
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); //Turn the trigger to idle
  long duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH); //make duration the wave that echo recieves back
  long dis = (duration/2) / 29.1; //divide by 2 for going there and back.                         ***Speed of sound***
  return dis; //Send the distance to function call
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your sketch (pin usage) is in conflict with the SD shield (SPI pins). Try using other pins.